# unknown error: DevTools returned unknown type:webvie

Tags: selenium-webdriver, window-handles

Unable to switch to new window in Chrome. I'm getting below error:

> unknown error: DevTools returned unknown type:webview

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen after Chrome auto updated (I know, we should really disable that). If you check [the release notes for ChromeDriver](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.15/notes.txt), you can verify if your Chrome and ChromeDriver versions are compatible.

By updating ChromeDriver to the most recent version, this error was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This is due an old ChromeDriver, check and update the ChromeDriver to the newest [here](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.19/).

Answer (score 0):

My answer is exactly the same as the others: your chromedriver needs updating.

However: If you are using ruby (selenium, watir, etc) then you are accessing chromedriver through a helper gem called chromedriver2-helper. This gem, as well as providing chromedriver in your path, also comes with a handy chromedriver updater - also in your path - called chromedriver-update. So from the command line, I would suggest you do the following:

```
# Make sure your chromedriver helper is up-to-date:
gem update chromedriver
# Now update chromedriver itself.
chromedriver-update
```

Once that's done, hopefully your selenium should just work.